# Map in $C(\mathbb{T})$ with constant modulus 1

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that a function in A($\mathbb{D})$ (analytic on the open disk and continuous on its boundary $\mathbb{T}$) with constant modulus on $\mathbb{T}$ is a finite Blaschke product. But what about a function $f\in C(\mathbb{T})$ with constant modulus 1? Is there a good characterization for what such a function would look like? Perhaps some combination of the aforementioned result for functions in the disk algebra and the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem?